# How do I set default value for Alfresco aspect property that can be multiple?

Tags: alfresco

I have to prepopulate my model with all options from constraint.
How do I set a default value for an aspect property in Alfresco that have multiple flag set to true? Is it even possible to pass array of items to default value?

```
<property name="aa:allowedTypes">
   <title>Allowed types</title>
   <type>d:text</type>
   <multiple>true</multiple>
   <default>cat,dog,chicken</default>
   <constraints>
     <constraint ref="aa:allowedTypesOption" />
  </constraints>
</property>

<constraints>
    <constraint name="aa:allowedTypesOption" type="LIST">
      <parameter name="allowedValues">
        <list>
          <value>cat</value>
          <value>dog</value>
          <value>chicken</value>
        </list>
      </parameter>
    </constraint>
</constraints>
```

It seems that cat,dog,chicken does not work, nor does ["cat","dog","chicken"]

Edit: Yep, there is no solution to this. It can be set up to fill this field on node creation with policy but not in model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default it is not possible to set multiple default values. default tag in content model is meant to set a single value, not designed to put multiple.

However, you can achieve this by implementing a rule/behavior which can set the multiple values at the time of node creation.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the Model Manager in Alfresco to accomplish your task.

You can have a "List of Values" for a property of a "Custom Type" and there is  field for "Default Value" as well. However I cannot say the same for when creating an "Aspect" and I do not see how an array of values can be passed within the creation of an aspect.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set multiple default values for an aspect property.

But you can achieve this by using any of the below Node Service policies.
For Ex: you can set multiple values using the method **onAddAspect**. Before adding the corresponding aspect you can do whatever customizations you want.

```
org.alfresco.repo.node.NodeServicePolicies  
beforeAddAspect
beforeArchiveNode
beforeCreateNode
beforeCreateStore
beforeDeleteAssociation
beforeDeleteChildAssociation
beforeDeleteNode
beforeMoveNode
beforeRemoveAspect
beforeSetNodeType
beforeUpdateNode
onAddAspect
onCreateAssociation
onCreateChildAssociation
onCreateNode
onCreateStore
onDeleteAssociation
onDeleteChildAssociation
onDeleteNode
onMoveNode
onRemoveAspect
onSetNodeType
onUpdateNode
onUpdateProperties
```